# What is the Complete Set of Shortest Axioms of Classical Conditional-Negation Propositional Calculus?

Tags: lo.logic

Suppose that we only have propositional variables and connectives.  Suppose our rules of inference are detachment {C$\alpha$$\beta$, $\alpha$} $\vdash$ $\beta$, and uniform substitution.  Suppose that we have a binary connective "C" and a unary connective "N".  In 1953 C. A. Meredith found what is currently the shortest single axiom of classical C-N (Conditional-Negation) propositional calculus [p. 302 of A. N. Prior's Formal Logic indicates this and references Prior's paper " 'Single Axioms for the Systems (C, N), (C, O), and (A, N) of the Two-valued Propositional Calculus' JCS, vol. i, No. 3 (July 1953), pp. 155-64.  Systems 1.5, 3.13, 6.13, 6.14.):

CCCCCpqCNrNsrtCCtpCsp.

Or using another prefix notation

→→→→→pq→¬r¬srt→→tp→sp.

So given the first notation, the formation rules are:

1. All lower case letters of the Latin alphabet, as well as any lower case letters of the Latin alphabet sub-scripted by Hindu-Arabic numerals are formulas.
2. If **x** is a formula, then so is N**x**.
3. If **x** and **y** are formulas, then so is C**x** **y**.  The space between the **x** and the **y** in "C**x** **y**" is not necessary.
4. Nothing else is a formula in this context.

To determine what is and what is not a formula the following suffices.

1. Assign -1 to all lower case letters, as well as all lower case letters which are sub-scripted.
2. Assign 0 to N.
3. Assign 1 to C.
4. Sum the assigned numbers as you precede from left to right throughout any given string.
5. A string will qualify as a formula if and only if it either starts and ends with -1, or if it starts with a member of {0, 1} and -1 is only reached at the spot corresponding to the last letter of the string, and that string ends with -1.

Now, via the above it turns out that any formula that starts with "C", has its antecedents corresponding to the longest subformulas which have a "0" corresponding to their last letter.  So looking at the above formula, we have

```
C  C  C  C  C  p  q  C  N  r  N  s  r  t  C  C  t  p  C  s  p
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
1  2  3  4  5  4  3  4  4  3  3  2  1  0  1  2  1  0  1  0 -1
```

The longest subformula which ends with the first "t" is thus CCCCpqCNrNsrt.  The longest subformula which ends with the second "p" is thus "Ctp", and "s" is the longest subformula corresponding to the third "0" spot.  Thus, the main breaks of the formula can get located by the following "|" marks.

```
 C|CCCCpqCNrNsrt|C|Ctp|C|s|p.
```

Furthermore, the main breaks of CCCCpqCNrNsrt is given by C|CCCpqCNrNsr|t, and so on.

Suppose we have a 2-valued model of C and N given by the following table:

```
C  0  1  N
0  1  1  1
1  0  1  0
```

Does there exist any shorter single axiom, which under the rules above allows us to deduce all tautologies, and only those tautologies in the 2-valued model?  Does there exist another single axiom of the same length?

**If there exists a unique shortest axiom up to re-symbolization of variables and connectives, what is the shortest axiom (which is a tautology) that allows us to deduce a known axiom system for classical propositional calculus, such as the following axiom set?**

1. CpCqp.  [p$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$p)].
2. CCpCqrCCpqCpr. [(p$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$r))$\rightarrow$((p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$(p$\rightarrow$r))].
3. CCNpNqCqp.  [($\lnot$p$\rightarrow$$\lnot$q)$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$p)].

**If there exists more than one shortest axiom, what is the set of such shortest axioms up to re-symbolization of variables and connectives?**

The length of an axiom is defined by the number of symbols it has when fully expressed as a well-formed formula in Polish/Lukasiewicz notation.

I've tried to find a way to compute all tautologies of a certain length in OTTER, but had no [success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893781/how-do-i-get-otter-to-generate-all-tautologies-of-a-certain-length).  There has existed some similar [work](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/AR/award-2001/fitelson.pdf) for shortest axioms in classical propositional calculus with the Sheffer Stroke, but in a private communication with one of the authors I've learned that they didn't do a search for the shortest axioms of the conditional-negation formulas for classical propositional calculus.

Comment: I would expect that many more people will understand the axiom if you were to write it in infix notation, rather than prefix notation. Also, you can use $\to$ and $\neg$ rather than C and N.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins In most cases, I'd agree with you, but this particular formula seems destined to be understood by very few people even if written in readable form.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The axiom would end up longer if it got written out in *an* infix notation.  I'm not just talking about the difference in brackets between (a$\rightarrow$b) and [a$\rightarrow$b].  The part of a definition of formulas which says "If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are formulas, then ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$) is a formula," indicates one infix notation.  The part of a definition of formulas which says "If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are formulas, then ($\alpha$)$\rightarrow$($\beta$) is a formula," indicates another infix notation.

Comment: There is no reason not to write the formula in a human-readable form, and just define its length to be the number of variables and connectives, ignoring brackets.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek There is no reason not to write the formula as I did above in words and define its length to be the number of "if"s, "not"s and positional words "first", "second", "third", "fourth", and "fifth".

Comment: In infix notation, perhaps slightly more readable than prefix: [(((p→q)→(¬r→¬s))→r)→t] → [(t→p)→(s→p)].

Comment: In words the axiom can get read as:

""If, if, if, if, if p, then q, then if not r, then not s, then r, then t, then if, if, t, then p, then if s, then p."  

or

"If, if, if, if, if the first, then the second, then if not the third, then not the fourth, then the third, then the fifth, then if, if, the fifth, then the first, then if the fourth, then the first.""

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Suppose we want to determine the length of a formula without a machine and have no other formulas around.  Do you find it *just* as easy to determine the length of [(((p→q)→(¬r→¬s))→r)→t] → [(t→p)→(s→p)], as  determining the length of CCCCCpqCNrNsrtCCtpCsp?

Comment: No, I find it much *easier*. There is no way I can visually count 20+ letters of line noise without making a mistake, whereas the redundant structure of the infix formula makes the task feasible. Anyway, this is quite besides the point. You are *communicating* with *humans*, and thus you should strive to use notation that is clearly readable for others. When the length of a formal expression is an issue, you need to state it in the post, not make people count it themselves.

Comment: Humans first used Polish notation on paper.  They wrote those papers for other humans.  I fail to see how it is not readable for humans.

Comment: Doug's comment "If, if, if, if, if p..." above, which surely helps to make the statement completely transparent, reminds me of the perfectly grammatical sentence, "Dogs dogs dogs bite bite bite."  Or similarly, "Cats dogs people pet chase purr."  And in the English class, while Mary had had "had," John had had "had had"; "had had" had had a greater effect on the teacher.

Comment: Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo?

Comment: Interesting jokes.  Do you want to make fun of the following set of sentences also?
"If p, then if q, then p.", and "If, if p, then if q, then r, then if, if p, then q, then if p, then r.":  Or how about these this set of sentences "If p, then if q, then p." "If, if p, then q, then if, if q, then r, then if p, then r."  "If, if p, then if p, then q, then if p, then q."

Comment: @DougSpoonwood, yes, it is readable for humans. No, it is not *easier to read* than *any one of the standard infix notations* for *most* humans. As evidence for this, I point to the fact that the vast majority of papers in logic written "recently" (say, last 30 years) use an infix notation. There's a huge gulf between "humans can understand it" and "humans can easily understand it" (as anyone who's read a paper by, e.g., Kleene can attest to :P).

Comment: Emil, yes, I would think so, because they have the opportunity and probably the inclination. But I wonder how many Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo there actually are...

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Given a countable infinity of "buffalo", the axiom "Buffalo buffalo-1 Buffalo buffalo-2 buffalo-1" indicates that we have a countable infinity of possible axiom sets with multiple axioms for propositional calculus. "Buffalo buffalo-1 Buffalo buffalo-2 buffalo-1" can get replaced by *any* of the theorems in the system "Buffalo buffalo-1 Buffalo buffalo-2 buffalo-1", under condensed detachment... or equivalently with the rules 1. {(Buffalo buffalo-x buffalo-y), buffalo-x} $\vdash$ buffalo-y and 2. uniform substitution for lower case buffalos.  Hence, the curiosity about...

Comment: the shortest possible axioms of propositional calculus.  It is clear to me that there exists a countable infinity of *single* axioms for propositional calculus, given countably infinite variables.  But, the shortest axiom question is much harder.

Comment: This question has been answered in 2021 by "Matthew Walsh & Branden Fitelson" in [Answers to Some Open Questions of Ulrich & Meredith](http://fitelson.org/walsh.pdf): There are six additional minimal axioms, which they provided (`CCpCCNpqrCsCCNtCrtCpt`
`CpCCqCprCCNrCCNstqCsr`
`CpCCNqCCNrsCptCCtqCrq`
`CpCCNqCCNrsCtqCCrtCrq`
`CCpqCCCrCstCqCNsNpCps`
`CCCpqCCCNrNsrtCCtpCsp`). The question contains more information than it needed, and is easy to understand for any professional mathematician, which this site aims for. Trouble in the comments was unwarranted, and it shouldn't have been closed.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know, but it is quite possible that the first question is an open problem, see [Ulrich's list of open problems](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~dulrich/Twenty-six-open-questions-page.htm).